# Add winlogon login method using C# and YubiKey

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, c#-4.0, winlogon

As for personal fun and challenge, I wanted to add a way to login on my own personal computers. All are currently using Windows 7.

Normally this would use ICredentialProvider or something like that. Basically the goal here is to have 2 way to login, the normal user/password one and the alternative (mine) with a Yubikey.

Is there any where I could look to find some resources on how to achieve this using C# ?

Comment: Did you ever find a nice solution to this?

Comment: @Cheesebaron not at all, but it was mostly for fun and games. Maybe it changed with Win8, maybe not. Although some solutions already exists for this kind of thing.

Comment: OK :) I was kind of thinking of replicating the knock on the phone thing you can do on a Mac with a paired iPhone to unlock your computer. Sure it is super unsecure etc. but it is super convenient.

Answer (score 2):

There is an article about implementing a [custom Credential Provider here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx), and there is [some samples here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1287ec56-77b4-48c4-8b58-35b7295d6c2c&displaylang=en). However, I do believe you need to implement a custom Credential Provider in native code, which would typically mean C/C++. The examples are in C.

You should probably do some googling before undertaking the task. Do be aware that [GINA](http://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Faa380543(VS.85).aspx&ei=K6RyTJi3OM7LswbkwsC5Bg&usg=AFQjCNEbTKp0BkxuN4HFIlBIENIbeOBWwQ) is the old Windows login mechanism, and has been removed from Windows since Vista (so you can ignore articles about that).