# Can I unlock a computer using vb.net application?

Tags: vb.net, windows, vbscript, passwords, unlock

I want to create an application that will run in the backgournd when my computer is locked, And will be able to unlock it in certain situations.

currently I have the code to only lock the computer :

```
   <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function LockWorkStation() As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Not LockWorkStation() Then
            Throw New Win32Exception()
        End If
    End Sub
```

So how can I unlock a computer with a vb.net application ?

Comment: Methinks allowing this would be a pretty substantial security risk?

Comment: why, lets say my application knows the user password (he typed it in my application before), and my application just uses it to log in.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565878/c-sharp-unlock-workstation - this might have some helpful pointers

Comment: I know, what is the problem ?,I can use VBscipt in vb.net